# mk-livestatus No UNIX Socket Existing

Tags: centos7, nagios, socket, check-mk

I'm currently in the process of setting up NagVis, and one of the prerequisites is that mk-livestatus be up and running on your Nagios server.

This is proving difficult.

The website for check_mk only has instructions on how to install all of check_mk, as far as I can tell, which I don't really need to do. I was going off these installation instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102832/how-to-install-mk-livestatus-on-nagios), with one difference: the path `/usr/lib/nagios/mklivestatus` is now `/usr/lib64/nagios/mklivestatus`. However, when I get to the final step and test it out by entering the command

```
echo 'GET hosts' | unixcat /usr/lib64/nagios/mk-livestatus/live
```

I get the following message:

```
No UNIX socket /usr/lib64/nagios/mk-livestatus/live existing
```

I've tried installing more recent versions of mk-livestatus, but every other version number I enter into the `wget` command just comes back with `ERROR 404: Not Found.` All the advice I've found relating to this problem seems quite out of date, so I'm having trouble puzzling this out.

I'm running Nagios 4.3.4 on a CentOS 7 server. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the socket could be anything, does `/usr/lib64/nagios/mk-livestatus/live` exist? If not, does the `live` socket exist somewhere else? Your livestatus configuration should probably contain the path where the socket is placed.